# bash: appc: command not found in appcelerator studio

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm trying to log into appcelerator studio, but nothing works, when I try it through terminal with appc login, I get this error: bash: appc: command not found.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install the CLI tools globally with `npm install -g alloy appcelerator titanium`. After that the `appc` command should be available in your CLI. Then you can run `appc login`. For a more details install instruction have a look at: [How to install Axway Appcelerator in combination with Atom](https://github.com/m1ga/titanium_with_atom)

Comment: It kinda worked, now I'm getting: An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot find module 'psl'
Cannot find module 'psl'

Comment: Where do you get that error? It sounds like you are trying to include a module that is not required before (e.g. with hyperloop)

Comment: Im getting that error in appcelerator studio terminal

Comment: psl is a node package that should be included in the appcelerator npm package (e.g. on linux: /usr/lib/node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/psl). Does `appc info` work in the command line? Did you install the packages globally?

Comment: appc info does not work and now I'm getting the old error again bash: appc: command not found.

Comment: make sure to run the command from a administration console if you have multiple users.

Comment: I'm running it from cmd.exe as administrator

Comment: you might want to join the Titanium Slack at tislack.org and ask again in the #helpme channel so we can discuss that a bit better